# Why do the Don Rosa comics frequently have a "story code" containing a date that is one year prior to the "date"?

Tags: comics, disney

I found this today: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Disney_comics_by_Don_Rosa

Observe the "Date" and "Story code" columns. For example, the one in the very bottom says "2006-05" for the "Date" column, but "D 2005-061" for the story code. The same goes for most/many of the entries; the year in the "story code" (because it pretty much *has* to refer to a year) is one year earlier than the "date".

My only guess is that they give the story code when the story script has been "accepted for production", and the "Date" refers to when it was actually published, which may take a full year or longer?